# how to ConvertDataSetToList for Excel data?

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following the below article:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/uploading-multiple-records-via-excel-upload-in-database-usin/

But here he didn't give the `ListConverter` class code how to write the code for `ConvertDataSetToList` in this sitiation?

Could anyone help me please?

Here  ListConverter class is a method to convert the DataSet To List here how to  do that?

I had tried as below

public class ListConverter
    {
        public ListConverter(DataSet ds)
        { }

```
    public List<T> ConvertDataSetToList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     var x=   ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Select(p => new oustanding()
        {
            CustomerID = p["CustomerID"].ToString(),
            Name = p["Name"].ToString(),
            PhoneNumber =Convert.ToInt64(p["PhoneNumber"]),
            Address = p["Address"].ToString(),
            ServiceProviderID = Convert.ToInt32(p["ServiceProviderID"]),
            TotalDue = p["TotalDue"].ToString()



        }).ToList();
     var list = x.ToList();
     return list;
```

It's showing Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'    C:\Users\NTC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Uploadusingentitty\Uploadusingentity.WebUI\AppHelper\ListConverter.cs    33  17  Uploadusingentity.WebUI
error

Comment: or could any one suggest me like similar article?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.listconverter%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: that's belongs to SharePointPermissionAttribute?

Comment: Here ListConverter class is a method to convert the DataSet To List here how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change these lines

```
ListConverter<Employee> converterObj = new ListConverter<Employee>(ds);
 List<Employee> lstData = converterObj.ConvertDataSetToList();
```

to

```
List<Employee> lstData = (from x in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           select new Employee
                           {
                               Address = x["Address"] != null ? x["Address"].ToString() : null,
                               Age = x["Age"] != null ? Int32.Parse(x["Age"].ToString()) : 0,
                               DOB = x["DOB"] != null ? x["DOB"].ToString() : null,
                               Email = x["Email"] != null ? x["Email"].ToString() : null,
                               EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(x["EmployeeID"].ToString()),
                               Name = x["Name"] != null ? x["Name"].ToString() : null
                           }).ToList<Employee>();

   or
```

declare `ListConverter` class

```
public class ListConverter
{
    public List<Employee> ConvertDataSetToList(DataSet ds)
        {
           List<Employee> lstData = (from x in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                               select new Employee
                               {
                                   Address = x["Address"] != null ? x["Address"].ToString() : null,
                                   Age = x["Age"] != null ? Int32.Parse(x["Age"].ToString()) : 0,
                                   DOB = x["DOB"] != null ? x["DOB"].ToString() : null,
                                   Email = x["Email"] != null ? x["Email"].ToString() : null,
                                   EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(x["EmployeeID"].ToString()),
                                   Name = x["Name"] != null ? x["Name"].ToString() : null
                               }).ToList<Employee>();
            return lstData ;
          }
}

List<Employee> lstData = ListConverter.ConvertDataSetToList(ds);
```

Comment: ListConverter<Employee> converterObj = new ListConverter<Employee>(ds);
to take ds as a parameter I created the constructor  public ListConverter(DataSet ds)
        { } is it correct?

Comment: No Declare ListConverter class. Have one static method to retun list of employees: public List<Employee> ConvertDataSetToList(Data set)(){//put above my logic}